# Building .apk and .aar library from same project

Tags: android, gradle, apk, project, aar

is it possible to build an apk and an aar library with gradle from the same project source?
Challenge is to modify the build.gradle so that both products will be built. Do you have any advice?

Comment: What would it mean for a project to be both an app and a library? What problem are you trying to solve by trying to have a project be both an app and a library?

Comment: I've an app including a lot of functionality and ui elements. A part of this functionality should now be released in a library, so that other companies can use it in their apps.

I know that we could move the sources of the library to a new library project and use the resultant library in the app, but we are feeling very comfortable in using library sources directly and not using it from the aar library (because of debugging and further development)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, Gradle offers me a really simple solution for this issue:
I've created a multi module project with Android Studio and Gradle (see http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-creating-a-multi-project-build/). One module for the app (Android Application Project) and one for the library (Android Library Project).

After moving all sources, that belong to the library, to the library project, I'm able to build the .aar file and the .apk file (which uses also sources from the library project, no problem thanks to the multi module project).

Comment: hello, did you manage to do it that way? I have an application and I have imported as Library my library, but when I generate apk, it only generated my apk not the aar

Comment: yes it works.
Did you list all your modules in the settings.gradle file?
In my case it looks like this: "include ':app', ':core'" (app is the application, core the library).

Also i've added a compile dependency in app's build.gradle:
flavorCompile project(':core')

Comment: This will only work, if you select "Build -> Rebuild Project" in Android Studio. Selecting "Build -> Make Project" only creates the APK but not the AAR file.
Another option is to build the project from the command line using "./gradlew assemble"